# param names and values in HTML

Tags: html, param

I am trying to learn the object and param tags in HTML. However I couldn't understand the attributes name and value for the param element.

The link below gives an example about "autoplay" parameter. However it starts to autoplay even if I change the value to "false".

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_param

Here are my questions:

1) Is the information in param element functional? Or does it only inform the one who reads the code? (I don't think so but the example in W3Schools doesn't work properly for me?

2) How can I learn valid param names and values? I couldn't find a list on Google. Is there such a list?

Comment: What type of file are you trying to play?

Comment: The example I showed with the link uses a .wav file. But I also want to learn the names and values can be used for other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to the "false" bit not working. It's probably a result of your specific browser, a browser default (always play content on this page?), or a rogue plugin.

The "false" option worked fine for me in the newest Firefox on Mac OS X 10.10

In general the various parameter options are defined by the plugin you're using (in this case it's probably quicktime) to playback/show the content.

Here's what looks to be an example doc for Quicktime:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ta26486

I'm guessing it's a little outdated but I think you'll get it. (hopefully!) :)

Comment: Both of the answers here seem very useful. Would you mind if I ask you how you understood what plugin was used? How can I learn what file invokes what plugin?

Comment: I just "right clicked" on the player (in my case, Firefox actually asked me to load the plugin at which point it showed the name of it). If you're using a 'player' (Javascript or Flash) it'll have its own set of options you should be able to find in the documentation (if there are any).

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-param-element),

> The `param` element defines parameters for plugins invoked by `object`
>   elements. It does not represent anything on its own.

Therefore, there is no list of standard `param`'s `name` and `value` possible values.

However, the plugin you use may have a documentation with the parameters it accepts.

---

Instead of relying on a plugin, consider using [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) to play sound files:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <!-- Fallback for old browsers: -->
  <object data="horse.wav">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
  </object>
</audio>
```

To avoid autoplay, just make sure you don't include [`autoplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-autoplay) attribute. Even if you set it to false `<audio autoplay="false">`, it will autoplay.